# Quickest way to transfer a file from remote Linux to Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I need to transfer a file (~15 Mb) from a remote Linux machine to my local Windows box over the Internet and I was just wondering what would be the best way to do it? The Linux machine is a server sitting behind firewalls so that solutions need to open other ports may not be suitable. I'm currently connected to the Linux machine via SSH(Putty) and I prefer to use the command line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you prefer the command line, try pscp.exe on the local machine, from the lovely Putty people.

```
pscp.exe <user>@<remote ip>:<remote file> <local file>
e.g. pscp.exe smith@122.100.150.161:/etc/hosts ./hosts
```

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 13):

I'd give `scp` a try. Or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net) if you want a GUI.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways:

1. python -m SimpleHTTPServer

   This will start a web server on port 8000 (if you need an alternate port, specify it as next argument) which will expose all files in the current directory and you could download them directly with the web browser or with any http downloader.
2. Use netcat! Just google for "netcat file transfer", you'll find a lot of examples.

Comment: Sure, either of these *would* work, but why require another port/configuration/etc when ssh is obviously already running, especially when considering that either of the above options sends the file across the network unencrypted.

Comment: It's a good recommendation, as he's asking for the *quickest* way.  I pipe tar through netcat all the time on a LAN when I want to reduce overhead for a large transfer.

Comment: @Warner, yes, that's correct. I guess I was reading too much into the question..."remote linux system" usually means across the WAN somehow, which in most cases, you'd want to use some encrypted method.

Comment: Good point.  Over the Internet, encrypted protocols are the best idea.

Comment: sorry, i should have stated clearer in the question. The question has been updated.

Comment: I just provided options. It's up to the guy who asked to pick the one that suits him best.

Answer (score 1):

my preference goes to filezilla, for it supports SSH protocol (as well as FTP and such)

http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Using **notepad++** with NppFTP plugin is another way. Its faster than **pscp.exe**

For download :

[image]

For Upload :

[image]